# Add xaml pages as child objects to panels

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm trying out some C# WPF and set up my Application. Usually I'd separate the views, so in my main windows I'd like to insert child xaml files in the main window xaml but I can't find a way to set the source for the page or something similar.

```
<Window x:Class="backset.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:backset"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<DockPanel>
    <!-- Menu Bar -->
    <Page DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <!-- How do I get this to load the MenuBar.xaml? -->
    </Page>

    <!-- Master -->
    <Page DockPanel.Dock="Left">
        <!-- This should load my MasterList.xaml -->
    </Page>

    <!-- Detail -->
    <Page DockPanel.Dock="Right">
        <!-- This should load my DetailsPage.xaml -->
    </Page>

    <!-- Status Bar -->
    <Page DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
        <!-- This should load my StatusBar.xaml -->
    </Page>
</DockPanel>
```

Or is a page a completely wrong approach.

Comment: What do you want to load from your 'child xaml' files? Are those `UserControl`'s?

Comment: It can be whatever it needs to be. Any xaml that includes a panel with all a panel could fit. It could be a Page or UserControl. Everything in it I could do directly in the main window, I just want to separate large parts to make it cleaner and somehow load those parts into the main window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. In WPF I can load a UserControl directly by name.

```
<Window x:Class="backset.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:backset"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<DockPanel>
    <!-- Menu Bar -->
    <local:MenuBar DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>

    <!-- Master -->
    <local:ApplicationList DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>

    <!-- Detail -->
    <local:ApplicationDetails DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>

    <!-- Status Bar -->
    <local:StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"/>

</DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using a UserControl instead of a Page since it doesn't come with all the built-in navigation features etc. Then you can either add the user control directly, like this:

```
<local:MenuBar DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
```

Or you can add a content presenter and bind the content:

```
<ContentPresenter DockPanel.Dock="Top" Content={Binding Path=MyMenuBarPage}/>
```